# What does a symbol (key) means in the simple_navigation gem configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, menu

Please tell me, what's the purpose of the first argument in the [simple_navigation configuration](https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation/wiki/Configuration) gem?

For example, look at this code:

```
SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
  navigation.auto_highlight = false
  navigation.items do |primary|
    primary.item :report_errors, "Errors Log", report_errors_path
    primary.dom_class = 'nav pull-right'
  end
end
```

According to wiki:

> a key (used for identifying the active navigation item in the controllers)

but as I noticed, `:report_errors` argument is only influences on the name of corresponding `id` attribute in HTML tag.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is a uniq symbol variable that Simple Navigation will refer to. You first pass the key of the item, and then a String that will be displayed for this item.

Example:

```
navigation.items do |primary|
  primary.item :my_books, 'My Books', books_path(user_id: current_user.id)
  primary.item :all_books, 'Show all books', books_path
  primary.item :his_books, 'Show his books', books_path(user_id: @other_user.id)
end
```

Each symbol (key) must be uniq to allow Simple Navigation to find back what item is used.